# Gorm is adding unwanted where clause that i don't need

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to query and get all the data using Postgres connection with gorm in golang.

My Gorm Model

```golang
    type WebsiteSlots struct {
    Id uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Settings string `gorm:"json"`
    AdsizeId int `gorm:"type:int"`
    WebsiteId int `gorm:"type:int"`
    AdSize Adsizes `gorm:"foreignkey:AdSizesId"`
    Website Websites `gorm:"foreignkey:WebsiteId"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"`
}

func (WebsiteSlots) TableName() string {
    return "website_ads"
}
```

My Query repository GetSlots() is producing

> "SELECT * FROM "website_ads"  WHERE "website_ads"."id" = 2 LIMIT 50
>   OFFSET 0"

this query . I don't know how this ""website_ads"."id" = 2" comes from?

```golang
type Slots struct {
    Container *container.Container
}

func (w *Slots) GetSlots(skip int , limit int) []models.WebsiteSlots {
    var results []models.WebsiteSlots
    sites := w.Container.Get("dbprovider").(*services.Database)
    postgresConnection := sites.PostgresConnection()

    postgresConnection.LogMode(true)

    var websiteslots models.WebsiteSlots
    resp, _ := postgresConnection.Debug().Find(&websiteslots).Limit(limit).Offset(skip).Rows()
    //i := 0
    for resp.Next() {
        results = append(results,websiteslots)
    }
    return results
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var websiteslots models.WebsiteSlots
    resp, _ := postgresConnection.Debug().Find(&websiteslots).Limit(limit).Offset(skip).Rows()
```

Find() expects a slice of struct. But your're supplying a single struct. I don't know if that's the reason of extra WHERE clause.

Comment: i guess the problem was will be a slice.Thank you very much! <3

Answer (score 1):

```
websiteslots := []models.WebsiteSlots{}
postgresConnection.Debug().Limit(limit).Offset(skip).Find(&websiteslots)
return websiteslots
```

Here you use `Find()` & `Row()` both thats may occour problem. You get result in `websiteslots` then why use `resp` to prepare result.